# How can I sync up users data in site collection and user information list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, user-profile, site-collection, active-directory, user-information-list

Few USER ID's are different in User Information List compared to site collection.

If I hover over on a user in Pages library, the user id is 10.
And the same user id is 20 in User Info List

how can I make User ID's same in site and User Information List?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have duplicates in User Information List which is by the way one in each site collection and all user information are stored in this list.

It can happen if you switch from Windows Authentication to Claims Based Authentication on web application sometime later (for example if you migrated from older version of SharePoint).

You can list all users with PowerShell and see the duplicates.

```
asnp *sharepoint*
$web = Get-SPWeb http://server/sites/site
$web.SiteUsers | ? {$_.IsDomainGroup -eq $false} | Sort-Object ID | select UserLogin, DisplayName, ID
$web.Dispose()
```

The only solution is to update the items and set fields (Author, Editor...) to correct (higher) User ID with PowerShell.

```
asnp *sharepoint*
$web = Get-SPWeb http://server/sites/site
$list = $web.Lists["Site Pages"]
$item = $list.GetItemById(1)
$item["Author"] = 20
$item["Editor"] = 20
$item.Update()
$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas Nespor, yes there was an upgrade from windows to claims authentication.                                                                                                  
 I see only 5 users have 2 different accounts, one is with windows authentication and other is with claims authentication.                                                   Except these 5 users, remaining all users don't have duplicates in User Information List, but ID's are different in site and User Information List.    Appreciate your help/inputs.